# Can I combine two power lines from power company

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

My house used to have two residents. So there are two 110v power sources from power company. Now I want to combine them into one so I can have bigger current. Is it possible and how?

Comment: Call an electrician!

Comment: @MarcusMuller XY-problem?

Comment: Ask the power company to combine them. If you try it yourself and they happen to be on different phases, that's serious Darwin Award material.

Comment: No. No No. NO NO NO. | While they MAY be on the same phase, combining them introduces issues which may lead to fire or death.  | Where are you located? What is the voltage and current or power ratings of the two circuits? | If you measure phase to phase on the two circuits and get 0V AC them they MAY be technically connectable, but probably not.

Comment: @LuyinSun - Is the purpose of your question to eliminate powering your house from two separate meters and stopping having to deal with two billings from the utility each month??

Comment: @MichaelKaras I already opened two accounts with them. I am ok with that. I just want to utilize all resource I paid for. =)

Comment: Two accounts in some locals may incur more total cost than one account using the same amount of energy. Worth checking into. Could go the other way too if your area has an upcharge for energy above a certain threshold on a given account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Possibly, but it's pointless

If you measure phase to phase on the two circuits and get 0V AC then you could short the two hot lines (and two neutrals) together and no current will flow (theoretically).

But what did you accomplish? Assuming, you don't fry yourself or burn down your house in the process... you started with 2 electrical boxes with X capacity each. You now have one box with 2X capacity (best case).

*The wiring in the walls and the circuits themselves (building codes) are still limited to their original values (typically 10A-20A).*

All you did was eliminate one electrical box at the cost of opening most of the walls in your house and moving the wires. You didn't add any circuits, you didn't increase the total site capacity.

Pointless.

If you want more outlets just wire some of them to one box and some to the other.

Consult a qualified electrician.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 questions here:

1. Can you convert one panel to a sub panel so that both sides are on the same service

Probably. You should be able to get an electrician to do this. It won't require ripping out any existing wiring and shouldn't be too expensive - though some big (expensive) wire needs to be run between the panels.

2. Can you connect the wires before the meter to get twice as much service capacity

I don't think so, but anyways this is none of your business. Call the electric company and tell them you want to cancel one service and upgrade the other. They will charge you the same whether they run new wires or not.

Answer (score 1):

Why bother?  You DO ALREADY have the full service available to you.

Say you have two 100A panels, you can get 100A out of one panel and 100A out of the other.   That's just fine.  Your house has a total of 200A available.  That is not a barrier to anything you want to do.  I know this because there's nothing you could buy that would, alone, need more than 100A.  The loads already present are already reasonably balanced between the two panels.  If you want to move them around to let you run something big out of one panel, just move one circuit at a time.  (as many as you like.)

If you need more *breaker spaces* in the panel, then add a subpanel.  The subpanel can be as many amps as the main panel it's branched off of.

Subpanels cannnot merge power from 2 main panels.

If you really want to double them up so you can have, say, a 200A panel, like I say that doesn't buy you much, but it's a conversation you must have with the power company, because **only they can do that**.  I'm not wagging my finger saying you need to get permission, I mean it isn't really possible to do it stealthy.

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution is to allocate your existing circuits to one or the other supply.

If you are not sure how to do this then, as has been suggested in the comments, get a qualified electrician.